# How to update origin Github branch from upstream without a merge commit

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, branching-and-merging

I know there are quite a lot of answers on this topic here, but they all seem to feature a single-branch setup.

So, I forked a repo to my Github (`origin`) then cloned it (local `develop`) and created several feature branches that I'd like to work on, which I also pushed to `origin` and set the local feature branches to track `origin`'s feature branches' changes (the main local branch is also `develop`, as well as the main `origin`'s one). Made some local commits,pushed to `origin`, opened a PR for this branch, but it's not merged yet, so the `origin`'s feature branch is both several commits ahead and behind the `upstream` branch on Github. If I update the `origin`'s feature branch (sync fork in web UI), it would create a merge-commit hell, spawning a lot of unwanted merge commits.

I know the feature branches should be rebased, but how exactly in this case? I simply need to sync `origin` feature branch with `upstream` (repo that has been forked initially) from my local CLI without pushing a commit to `origin`.

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR

This can be fairly easily be solved by having both `upstream` and `origin` (your fork) as two remotes of your local sandbox.

##### Details

From your clarifications in the comments below, you want to bring the changes from `upstream/develop` into `origin/feature` without a merge commit. To do that, you need to rebase `origin/feature` onto `upstream/develop`.

To do that, you need a sandbox with two remotes:

```
git clone <origin URL>
cd <sandbox name>
git remote add upstream <upstream URL>
git fetch upstream
```

Now when you look at your logs locally, you will see both `upstream/develop` and `origin/feature`. Assuming your local `feature` is currently up-to-date with `origin/feature`, rebase it onto `upstream/develop`:

```
git rebase upstream/develop
```

And now you can force push that to your fork (after making sure a force push is really what you want):

```
git push -f origin feature
```

At this point `origin/feature` has been effectively rebased onto `upstream/develop` and is no longer behind it by any commits. Your PR from `origin/feature` to `upstream/develop` should also automatically see the new version.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple. In fact, there is no `upstream/feature` branch because the feature branch hasn't been merged into `upstream`'s develop branch yet and I don't have write access to the `upstream` repo. So I create a feature branch at my `origin` github repo and create a PR for this particular branch, that is merged with main `upstream`'s `develop` branch if all the CI checks are successful. What should I be rebasing in this case, if there's nothing to rebase onto?

Comment: I can update my `origin` to the current state of `upstream/develop` from Web UI easily, but it will spawn a merge commit like `Merge branch '%reponame%:develop' into `feature`. But I want to do it locally from PyCharm/CLI.

Comment: It's kinda hard to follow your logic here. Can you draw a graph showing the different branches, locally, or origin and on upstream, and show explicitly what you want updated to what? The annoying but correct answer is, Git is a swiss army knife that will let you do just about anything. Looking at your graph, it might be obvious what to do with the right combination of fast-forward merges and rebases. Whatever you want to do, it's almost certainly possible, but I don't have enough information to get you there.

Comment: Sure, I will elaborate. Here are the repos:

1. `upstream/develop` - the original repo, that was forked. Doesn't have my feature branches, but does have my PR from a feature branch below waiting to be merged
2. `origin/develop` - my fork on my personal Github page. Has branches like `origin/feature`
3. local repo `develop`. Has feature branches like `feature`, is set to track changes from `origin/develop`.

Now, what I want to do is pull changes from `upstream/develop` into `origin/feature` from a local machine without causing a merge commit spawn.

Comment: Then all you should need is `git checkout feature`, make sure it's up to date with `origin/feature`, and `git rebase `upstream/develop`. Push that with `git push -f origin feature` and you're all set. The PR from `origin/feature` to `upstream/develop` should automatically see the updated PR branch. The only different between this and my answer above is where your rebase to.

Comment: @Anvbis I updated my answer to reflect these clarifications.